# jQuery Knob not loaded after it's inserted into the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I defined a featureGenerator function to generate a jQuery knob on the fly in the HTML. However, after inserting this knob, all the properties of the knob were gone even though the Browser Inspector did confirm the code inserted. So I tested running the function outside of the Jquery and it works normally. Can anyone pleaseee tell me what I did wrong? Thank you!

The Knob I used is [here...](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/)

JSFiddle [here...](http://jsfiddle.net/jn4rW/1/)

```
function featureGenerator(htmlID, feature, initStatus1, initStatus2, idName) {

        if (feature === "knob") {htmlID.innerHTML="<div idName='"+id+"'>"+
                "<div id='myOuterKnob' style='position:absolute;left:4px'>"+
                "<input class='knob' id='outerKnob' data-width='180' data-height='180' "+
                "data-thickness='.4' data-angleOffset=-125 data-displayInput=false "+
                "data-angleArc=250 data-step='5' data-fgColor='#1e8bf2' data-bgColor='#d4eeec' "+
                "data-linecap=round value='"+initStatus1+"'></div>"+

                "<div id='myInnerKnob' style='position:absolute;left:44px;top:40px;display:block;'>"+
                "<input class='knob' id='innerKnob' data-width='100' data-height='100' "+
                "data-thickness='.5' data-angleOffset=-125 data-displayInput=false "+
                "data-angleArc=250 data-step='5' data-fgColor='#1e8bf2' data-bgColor='#d4eeec' "+
                "data-linecap=round value='"+initStatus2+"'></div></div>";
        }
      }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".knob").knob({
                        'min':0
                        ,'max':250
                        });

        $(".classname1").click(function(){
          $(this).find(".togglerRound").toggle("fold", 250);

          featureGenerator(($(this)).get(0).childNodes[0].childNodes[0], "knob", 0, 0, "146A");

        });
    })
```

Comment: You initialise knob() on document.ready but it doesn't exist until you create it onclick later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! Probably due to the knob being generated by jquery, I actually had to do appendChild instead of inserting a chunk of html text. Below is what I ended up using, creating DOM childrens and setting attributes one by one.

```
function insertDOM(tag, att){
  var fragment = document.createElement(tag);
  for (var a in att){
    if (att.hasOwnProperty(a)){
      fragment.setAttribute(a, att[a]);
    }
  }
  for (var i = 2 ; i < arguments.length ; i++){
    if (arguments[i].nodeType == 1 || arguments[i].nodeType == 3) {
      fragment.appendChild(arguments[i])}
  }
  return fragment;
}

  var fragmom = insertDOM("div", {'id': ipIdentifier})
  var frag1 = insertDOM("div", {'class':"sameOuterKnob",'style': "position:absolute;left:4px;"})
      frag1.appendChild(insertDOM("input", {'class':"knob",'data-width':"180",'data-height':"180",'data-thickness':"0.4",'data-angleOffset':-125,'data-displayInput':false,'data-angleArc':250,'data-step':"5",'data-fgColor':"#1e8bf2",'data-bgColor':"#f4f4f4",'data-linecap':'round','value':initStatus1}))
  var frag2 = insertDOM("div", {'style': "position:absolute;left:44px;top:40px;display:block"})
      frag2.appendChild(insertDOM("input", {'class':"knob",'data-width':"100",'data-height':"100",'data-thickness':"0.4",'data-angleOffset':-125,'data-displayInput':false,'data-angleArc':250,'data-step':"5",'data-fgColor':"#1e8bf2",'data-bgColor':"#f4f4f4",'data-linecap':'round','value':initStatus2}))
  fragmom.appendChild(frag1);
  fragmom.appendChild(frag2);
  htmlID.appendChild(fragmom);
```

Answer (score 2):

So you are dynamically inserting the code for knobs after trying to initialize them. Of course there is nothing to initialize since knobs aren't there yet. That's why it doesnt work.

You have to initialize a knob after (not before) you generate a knew one. So you should move this:

```
$(".knob").knob({'min':0,'max':250});
```

At the end of your featureGenerator function.

And even better change it so you target an individual knob ID instead of the whole class:

```
$("#newKnobIDHere").knob({'min':0,'max':250});
```

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jn4rW/3/
style is completely off, but the knob works.

You didn't include the knob library and you were calling knob constructor before having knob HTML.

Comment: I already tried putting that line AFTER the insertion, but doesn't seem to work either. However, I will see if pinpointing an ID would help. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could make a jsfiddle of this.

Comment: Just tried that again with the ID instead of the knob class, still no go for some reason

Comment: The ID is simply to not retarget all the existing knobs, just the new one, but yeah that won't solve the problem. I really thought that the problem was in the wrong order of operations, I don't know now. Put up a fiddle and I can play with it.

Comment: JSFiddle added to the question above

Comment: Updated my answer, here's the fiddle with a working knob: http://jsfiddle.net/jn4rW/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, now I'm finally getting somewhere. However, most of the customized attributes were still not shown (those data-xxxx).